# File not found?

Tags: java, file-io

I have an assignment and we have a couple of classes given, one of them is a filereader class, which has a method to read files and it is called with a parameter (String) containing the file path, now i have a couple of .txt files and they're in the same folder as the .java files so i thought i could just pass along file.txt as filepath (like in php, relatively) but that always returns an file not found exception!

Seen the fact that the given class should be working correctly and that i verified that the classes are really in the same folder workspace/src as the .java files i must be doing something wrong with the filepath String, but what?

This is my code:

```
private static final String fileF = "File.txt";
private static final ArrayList<String[]> instructionsF =
CreatureReader.readInstructions(fileF);
```

Comment: That cannot be all of your code, as it is not a valid Java class.  Please update the question with the minimum, executable code able to reproduce your issue.  You should at least include the Java file IO calls.

Comment: It's not about where the .java files are, the current working directory is where you run the executable from.

Comment: Listen to Falmarri! file.txt should be in the directory where you call java Main

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this:

```
File here = new File(".");
System.out.println(here.getAbsolutePath());
```

somewhere in your code. It will print out the current directory of your program.

Then, simply put the file there, or change the filepath.

Comment: Actually the java takes the main folder as 'current folder' (found out thanks to your little test) so i just have to do src/... (class files are in still another directory)

Comment: This depends on the way you run your Java program.. in any case, this test shows current working directory

Comment: So, it is probably Eclipse, or other editor that runs program from project folder. Falmarri explained why.

Answer (score 3):

Two things to notice:

1. check if "File.txt" is really named like that, since it won't find "file.txt" -> case sensitivity matters!
2. your file won't be found if you use relative filenames (without entire directory) and it isn't on your classpath -> try to put it where your `.class` files are generated

So: if you've got a file named `/home/javatest/File.txt`, you have your source code in `/home/javatest/`  and your `.class` files in that same directory, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you class is in package and you have placed the files as siblings then your path must include the package path.  As suggested in other answers, print out the path of the working directory to determine where Java is looking for the file relative from.